# why is my form div at bottom?

Tags: html, css, forms

why is my form div at bottom of parent div? it wants me to say more, but the question has been asked and it's pretty clear... why is the form div appearing at the bottom of my header div?  i know i can hack it and give it a negative top margin, but I KNOW that's not proper form.  what gives?  thx.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>

<body>
     <div id="header">
        <div id="logo"></div>
        <div id="login">
        <input type="text" placeholder="EMAIL ADDRESS" value="" name="email" id="user">

        </div><!-- end login div -->
     </div><!--end header div -->

</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
input {
    float: right;
    margin-left:15px;
}

#header {
    background-image:url(images/headerGradient.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    width:auto;
    height:72px;
    display:block;
}

#logo {
    background-image:url(images/logo.png);
    width: 182px;
    height: 66px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin-left: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because your logo div has no floating style set.
Try to add

```
float:left
```

to #logo div

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eyMJa/1/

Answer (score 0):

Using float in Css I have found becomes really annoying and makes getting layout how you want it kinda difficult, Unless you can watch a fair few youtube video's until you master it.

I'm trying to use:

```
     position:absolute;
```

instead, and then setting

```
    top:Number of Pixels or percentage/em;
    right:Number of Pixels or percentage/em;
    bottom:Number of Pixels or percentage/em;
    left:Number of Pixels or percentage/em;
```

also

```
    position:relative;
```

Seems to add blank space in the dimensions of the div again messing up the layout, where Absolute acts kind of like float, but without the annoying interactive or page jerking of the other two methods.

If you do use float for whatever reason, remember to add Clear float after each time you use it unless you specifically need to keep it.

Hope this helps